# How would I want to see you!

Tags: inversion, exclamatives

> How would I want to see you!

Does this mean "Oh boy, do I want to see you!"?

Is it also possible to say...

> How beautiful would you be in this dress!

to mean "Oh, you would look so beautiful in this dress, so wear it!"

Comment: I have edited your question for formatting; before you post your next question you might consult [**this**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/996/minor-recurring-formatting-errors-and-how-to-avoid-them) post on our Meta section, which will help you make your question more attractive to answerers.

Answer (score 3):

1. These exclamatory constructions do not take subject/auxiliary inversion; they are composed with *How* + an ordinary indicative sentence.

   > How beautiful you would be in this dress!
2. The first should be written without the *would*, exactly as your paraphrase is:

   > How I want to see you!

   The *would* is employed only to express your desire under hypothetical circumstances:

   > If you were to perform at Carnegie Hall, how I would want to see you!
3. In any case, these *How* constructions are almost exclusively literary today; you are unlikely to encounter them in conversation, and to use them would suggest to your hearers that you were attempting to sound like a character from a 19th-century novel.

Comment: Then what is this from the Atlantic Monthly?

Comment: @user8153 Can you provide a link?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22how+beautiful+is+this+flower!%22&start=10&tbm=bks

Comment: How beautiful is this flower of wood and iron, which we were ready to pass by without wasting a look upon it !

Comment: @user8153 That is from the Atlantic Monthly for August, **1890**. QED. Inversion was practised in those days. Note that heavy NP subject, which *must* fall at the end to accommodate the even heavier relative.

Comment: but you implied that my versions were grammatically wrong. so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @user8153 The construction itself calls for ordinary order, and your sentences do not have the particular constituents which demand inversion. Note that the author of the story in which that sentence appears has taken care to represent the author of the sentence as an eccentric, a poet manqué given to "extravagances and crotchety whims". His contorted syntax reflects his contorted inner life.